# How to model SQL table relationship when only entities with a certain role are valid targets for a foreign key

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I want to design an SQL database for the following business situation: There are **employees** with two roles: **project managers** and **task workers**. Project managers own **projects**, projects consist of **tasks** and task workers own tasks.

I have two ideas on how to model this:

1. Use *four* tables project_managers, task_workers, projects and tasks where projects has a foreign key to project_managers and tasks has a foreign key to task_workers. This seems awkward to me because project_managers and task_workers are both employees and contain the same columns.
2. Use *three* tables employees, projects, tasks where projects and tasks both have a foreign key to employees. The problem here is to ensure that only employees with role project manager are allowed to own projects and only employees with role task worker are allowed to own tasks. **How can I accomplish this**? For example, I don't see how to do it with check constraints. A quick sketch of the model can be seen in the following picture: [image]

If there are better ways to model this, I'm also interested in them. The problem seems like it should have a standard solution.

Answer (score 1):

To support schema evolution, you might create a workers table with just the id column, FKed to Employees, and a projectManagers table with just the id column, FKed to Employees.

If you're sure that only one worker will own a task, you you make the workers.id an FK from Tasks, and the same with projectManagers.   (if not, you would create a workerTaskAssocs table, (just making up names here) that would have a composite pk of worker_id and task_id, with each column FKed appropriately.

One can imagine that as the schema evolves, you'll find more attributes that are specific to workers and projectManagers, and you can add them in the appropriate table

This kind of thing is generally considered normalization, which is indeed a standard solution in the world of database design.   The proliferation of tables is a side-effect of normalization, which can be mitigated with views.

Comment: Rearrangements for subtypes/inheritance/polymorphism is not normalization. Normalization decomposes into components that natural join back to the original.